# How can i filter content in codeigniter based on this week, last week, 3 weeks ago and last month

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am kinda blank as to how to add filter options to a dropdown box and display the content based on the items in the dropdown list.

Here is my code:

```
<select class="select-style">
   <option value="this-week">This Week</option>
   <option value="last-week">Last Week</option>
   <option value="3-weeks">3 Weeks ago</option>
   <option value="last-month">Last Month</option>
</select>
```

This is the code of the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered padding-bottom-20 background-4-tablist">
            <thead>
                <tr class="row text-center">
                    <th class="padding-left-9">DATE ACCEPTED</th>
                    <th class="padding-left-9">PROJECT NAME</th>
                    <th class="padding-left-9">BUYER NAME</th>
                    <th class="text-center">AMOUNT</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
            <?php foreach($get_approved_project_list as $row)
            {
            $p_date=strtotime($row->p_submitdate);
            ?> 
                <tr class="row text-center">
                    <td class="col-md-3 info_1"><?php echo date('d-m-y',$p_date); ?></td>
                    <td class="col-md-3 info_1"><?php echo $row->p_title; ?></td>
                    <td class="col-md-3 info_1"><?php echo $row->p_buyname; ?></td>
                    <td class="col-md-3 info_1 text-center"><?php echo $row->p_totalpri; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>

            </tbody>

        </table>
```

Note: I have posted only views

Comment: I have been looking at code and nothing in codeigniter so far. I have never worked on such a thing before

Comment: while fetching data, you can write that conditions in query.